# Launch grunt task passing params on git commit

Tags: git, gruntjs

I am starting with grunt, I have defined this task and work like a charm:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

grunt.initConfig({

    jshint: {
        force: false,
        options: {
            evil: true,
            regexdash: true,
            browser: true,
            wsh: true,
            trailing: true,
            multistr: true,
            sub: true,
            loopfunc: true,
            expr: true,
            jquery: true,
            newcap: true,
            plusplus: false,
            curly: true,
            eqeqeq: true,
            globals: {
                jQuery: true
            }
        },
        src: ['workspace/**/*.js']
    }

});


grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
grunt.registerTask('default', ['jshint:src']);


};
```

Now, I would like to launch this task passing the src like a param (with git commited files).

I have tried this from a **pre-commit** script in my ***.git*** folder, but it does´t work:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('grunt jshint', {
       cwd: 'C:\\workspace',
       src: 'subfolder\\**\\*.js'
     }, function (err, stdout, stderr) {

  console.log(stdout);

  var exitCode = 0;
  if (err) {
    console.log(stderr);
    exitCode = -1;
  }

  process.exit(exitCode);
});
```

How can I pass params in execution time to my grunt task?

Thanks a lot, best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to pass command line parameters to grunt, you have to:

1. on the command line, use the syntax `--paramName=value`
2. in the gruntfile, use `grunt.option('paramName')`

So in your case you would call

```
exec('grunt jshint --src=subfolder\\**\\*.js', {cwd: 'C:\\workspace'}, function (err, stdout, stderr) {...});
```

and you gruntfile would be:

```
jshint: {
    (...)
    src: [grunt.option('src')]
}
```